# Error con el comando runserver de Django

Tags: python, django

Intentando correr el servidor local de Django me aparece el siguiente error en la terminal al correr usando `runserver`.

Este es el código:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in        import_module
    __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named registration
```

¿Por qué pasa esto y cómo puedo evitar que vuelva a suceder?

Comment: el error es claro, no tienes el modulo llamado "registration". crealo o encuentra el que ya tenías.

Comment: Donde se supone que deberia de estar? 
 En que archivo ? actualmente estoy trabajando en ST.

Comment: que significa ST? es un modulo de tu app el que falta, por lo general debería estar al mismo nivel que el resto de plugins, puedes agregar el archivo config principal?

Comment: Busca el archivo donde tienes la línea "introducir el código aquí" y pones tu código para nosotros verlo, porque solo pusiste el error que te aparece. Aunque el mensaje de error es claro `ImportError: No module named registration`, que quiere decir que no importaste el modulo `registration`

Comment: @moscoquera supongo que ST debe ser Sublime Text.

Comment: Si, ST significa Sublime Text

Comment: @G.Michel si estas usando django-registration en tu `INSTALLED_APPS` asegúrate de haberlo instalado en tu sistema o entorno virtual. Actualiza tu pregunta e incluye el código relevante de tu `settings.py`

Comment: es probable que registration no este creado, o contenga un error

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, si no estoy mal has creado una aplicación llamada registration y se te ha olvidado agregarlo a la configuración de aplicaciones instaladas:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'registration',
]
```

Añade la aplicación a la lista de aplicaciones instaladas y ya está, o bien, es un paquete externo que has usado para trabajar en django y no la has agregado ocurre ese problema.